# The election banner is not shown on the main site close to the beginning of the election

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, election

It is 8 hours until [the election](https://askubuntu.com/election) begins. Currently no election banner is shown on the main site but the election banner is showing on the meta site.

The main site:

[image: Main site, no election banner]

The meta site:

[image: Meta site, election banner]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is by design. Banners on the front page have a max display time of [48 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75409/close-button-for-community-moderator-election-is-underway-notification/75421#75421). For the past week we've been re-adding the banner to detail that the election is in the nomination phase. With just a few hours left in the nomination period, I've decided to just wait until the next automatically generated banner pops up (which will announce the start of the final election) run it's course then continue to re-add that banner throughout the final election period. Since meta is designed to be questions and announcements about the sites it doesn't fall into the same "2 day banner limit" as the main site does.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. It might indeed be good to re-add the banner during the election because the fact that moderators are elected may be a new thing, even unknown, to many users (I take it that we want as many people as possible to participate and vote in the election).